# Linear regression for samples of varying sizes

Tags: regression, linear-model

I have a data set of code patches and the bugs they produce. I'm using ordinary least squares to find a line which predicts bugs based on some attributes about the patch, such as the department which produced the code, how many issues were found in design, etc.

One thing is that the patches vary in size, and larger patches will (obviously) create more bugs. I'm trying to think of how I should handle this, and I came up with several options:

1. Use patch size (lines of code changed) as an independent variable. The problem with this is that I think I really want to predict defect "density". E.g. the Sales department might cause one bug every 15 lines of code, but the shipping people cause one every 30 lines of code. So I would need a variable like "department * lines of code changed", which I worry is more sensitive to overfitting.
2. Break it into samples of equal size. E.g. if a change to 10 lines of code caused 2 bugs, I pretend that this was actually 10 changes, each of which caused .2 bugs.
3. Divide through by the size and then weight by the size. i.e. minimize $\sum w_i(\frac{y_i}{w_i} - f(\vec{x_i}))^2$.

Are any of these preferable, or is there another option I should be using? I assume this must be a pretty standard problem to have, but I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: 1) Ability to find (and **introduce**) bugs is an individual trait, having little to do with the department. 2) Code patches are supposed to **fix** bugs (unless the QA process is not working in your organization). 3) Why are your salesmen coding instead of selling products?

Comment: Given that bugs is a count variable you probably shouldn't be using linear regression at all, but some form of count regression such as Poisson or negative binomial.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you, I have never heard of Poisson regression, but it sounds useful (Often bug creation modeled as Poisson distributed). I *think* I still have the problem of interaction between patch size and the other variables though, no?

Comment: Yes, that problem is separate.

Comment: I am not expert in this field, but "lines of code" seems problematic as a variable.... Different languages and different styles within a language, will produce more or fewer lines to do the same thing.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, those are valid criticisms. However, my goal is to predict bugs, not "explain" why those bugs occur, so if it turns out that one group has a higher density than another, it could be stylistic. (And we all use the same language). Also, my data set is fairly large.

Comment: @Xodarap, I see much uncertainty about the **dependent** variable you want to analyze/predict. Do you currently work with number of bugs per line of code? Forget about this curious "department*LOCs changed", BTW, because the variable makes no sense at all.

On independent variables: please consider adding time since the initial operating capability of the system, and some quantitative measure of the requirements behind the patch.

Comment: @DeerHunter: The dependent variable is bugs. Thank you for your comments about the experiment design, but I think a full explanation of what I'm doing goes outside the scope, and I would prefer to have an answer about the question I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of scope and the left-hand side var. What is the question then, since the only option that remains from the ones you described is:
LHS: `bugs` RHS: `department`, `patch size`

Comment: If your data set is large, why are you worried about overfitting (in the original question)?

Comment: @Peter: In backtesting, these methods do *much* better on the training than the testing samples (as measured by $r^2$). Of course some of that is to be expected, but I hope to minimize it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Interesting problem.

Comment: @Peter: I found [this link](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/user-guide-by-distribution/z/poisson_regression) which talks about Poisson regression based on an "exposure time". It seems like if I could have my "exposure time" be the number of lines of code changed, this would fit nicely. Do you think so? Do you know what it's called when you do regression with a non-fixed time window? I can't find any sources on it.